# delphi, mongo db insert error

Tags: delphi, mongodb

Сначала запрос проходит, но потом такой еррор. Ругается на спец символы. Если убрать, то все норм.
Пример кода: https://github.com/Int64x86/Documents/blob/main/test%20Mongo.rar

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
unit Unit110;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,
  Grijjy.MongoDB, Grijjy.MongoDB.Protocol, Vcl.StdCtrls, Grijjy.Bson;

type
  TForm110 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form110: TForm110;
  Client: IgoMongoClient;
  Database: IgoMongoDatabase;
  Collection: IgoMongoCollection;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm110.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  arr: array[0..5] of TgoBsonDocument;
  i: Integer;
begin

//
  try
    arr[0] := TgoBsonDocument.Create.Add('Login', 'RE%2F\%2F-2').Add('Password', 'too').Add('Domain', 'gmail.com');
    arr[1] := TgoBsonDocument.Create.Add('Login', '0goo1acc0').Add('Password', '0gooacc0').Add('Domain', 'gmail.com');
    arr[2] := TgoBsonDocument.Create.Add('Login', '0goo1a11cc0').Add('Password', '10gooa11cc0').Add('Domain', 'gmail.com');
    arr[3] := TgoBsonDocument.Create.Add('Login', '0ggggffgf').Add('Password', 'fm021019952x').Add('Domain', 'pito.com');
    arr[4] := TgoBsonDocument.Create.Add('Login', 'tds1fest').Add('Password', '12345fsdsd6').Add('Domain', 'gmail.com');
    arr[5] := TgoBsonDocument.Create.Add('Login', 'tee1ewfsdsft').Add('Password', '12345dsafsd6').Add('Domain', 'gmail.com');

    memo1.Lines.Add('Rows added: ' + Collection.InsertMany(arr).ToString)

  except
    on E: Exception do
      memo1.Lines.Add(E.Message)
  end;

end;

procedure TForm110.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

  procedure createTable;
  var
    level: TgoMongoValidationLevel;
    action: TgoMongoValidationAction;
    collaction: TgoMongoCollation;
    validator: TgoBsonDocument;
  begin
    level := TgoMongoValidationLevel.vlOff;
    action := TgoMongoValidationAction.vaWarn;
    collaction.Locale := 'ru';
    collaction.CaseLevel := false;
    collaction.CaseFirst := TgoMongoCollationCaseFirst.ccfOff;
    collaction.Strength := 1;
    collaction.NumericOrdering := False;
    collaction.Alternate := TgoMongoCollationAlternate.caNonIgnorable;
    collaction.MaxVariable := TgoMongoCollationMaxVariable.cmvSpace;
    collaction.Backwards := false;
    validator := TgoBsonDocument.Create;
    //
    try
      Database.CreateCollection('M5', false, 0, 0, level, action, validator, collaction)
    except
    end;
  end;

begin
  Client := TgoMongoClient.Create('localhost');
  Database := Client.GetDatabase('accounts');

  createTable;
  Collection := Database.GetCollection('M5');
  Collection.CreateIndex('Unigue', ['Login', 'Password'], true);
  Collection.CreateIndex('Search', ['Login'], false);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Минимальный воспроизводимый пример сможете предоставить?

Comment: @Kromster Да, пожалуйста. 
https://github.com/Int64x86/Documents/blob/main/test%20Mongo.rar
на пк установлен офф софт MongoDB Compass

Comment: Минимальный, в теле вопроса. А не ссылку )

Comment: ммм, походу понял. в индексом поле если не будет спец символов то норм все